# Office API - This add in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I am simply following the tutorials to create the Office AddIn using Office API and it is not working well. I am getting an error - *This add in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.*

**Tutorial Ref.** - [Build your first PowerPoint task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio)

**Environment** (*I tried/have*)

1. Windows 11
2. Visual studio - 2019 (16.11.33801.447) / Visual studio - 2022 (17.6.33723.286)
3. Office 365 (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 32-bit
4. Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime (114.0.1823.58)
5. Checking for PowerPoint

**Issue**
[image]

**Observation**

- Not working with Visual Studio **F5** (*With debug*)
- Working well with Visual Studio **Ctrl+F5** (*Without debug*) (*refer #3 of above image*)
- When error occurs (*#1 of above image*) - it shows Restart message with gray background and right-click is not working for the Inspect page.
- After pressing Restart, same message with white background and right-click is working (*#2 if above image*)
- Also, if we check error and not error case (*#2 and #3*), source tab of inspect has different values - one with no domain/page and one with page
- When error occurs at the same time the other add in has also same error and not working. I did notice with Script lab Add In.
- I think, I noticed same issue with Excel tutorial as well.
- I also found a few reference links but still no luck.

  - [Add-In could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417310/add-in-could-not-be-started)
  - https://support.fyidocs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056066672--This-add-in-could-not-be-started-Close-this-dialog-to-ignore-the-problem-or-click-Restart-to-try-again-
- Office and VS version looks proper - [Browsers and webview controls used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)
- I did check quickly with Yeoman generator and it is working fine.

**Question**

1. How to figure this out what's the problem here?
2. Am I missing anything to make it run?
3. Is this known issue of Office API and VS?

Comment: When you get situation #1 or #2, try putting the URL (from the `<SourceLocation>` element in the manifest) into a browser and see if the add-ins home page opens. Also, install the [Fiddler tool](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare the raw Request and Response in each of your three situations.

Comment: My guess is an issue w/ your Manifest.xml. Did you build project w/ Yeoman or VS?

Comment: When posting a question, it helps to follow this (make a reproducible, minimal example) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . With out this, we can only guess and take shots in the dark. Half the time, you will resolve your own issue while trying to make your question as "minimal" as possible.

Comment: Can you update w/ some code and/or your manifest? Happy to revert downvote if you include steps to reproduce.

Comment: @rickkirkham - In all the cases (working and not working), the `<SourceLocation>` location URL is working well on the browser. Regarding the fiddler, I have seen a 403 error but it seems to be seen during the working case as well. So. no luck at all.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers - It looks like you haven't read the details well. But fine, let me answer your questions here. 1. I simpling following the tutorial steps - nothing else. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio 2. I am checking with Visual Studio 3. Yeoman working fine. 4. I knew, the question should have "minimal" details, but to reduce back and forth, I have tried to add all cases which I tried.   Hope this will help you to answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Good luck! No code = no help from me!

Comment: Based on your symptoms, I think that the built-in VS debugger is causing the problem. The Office Add-in project templates in VS haven't been updated in years. 2 things to try: (1) Launch with Ctrl-F5 and then attach the VS debugger to the process after the add-in is running. (2) Launch with Ctrl-F5 and use the browser tools to debug: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio#use-the-browser-developer-tools

Comment: I would try uninstalling `Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime (114.0.1823.58)` to see if thats the issue.